# Example of ad hoc thread confinement in Java

Tags: java

I am reading the book "Java concurrency in practice". The authors did not provide any example for ad hoc thread confinement, only says it "describes when the responsibility for maintaining thread confinement falls entirely on the implementation".

Can anyone please give an example? I cannot understand its difference to stack confinement, ThreadLocal etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I also had problems understanding the text about ad-hoc thread confinement. But with help of https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2013/cmsc433/Notes/10-CMSC433-Confinement.pdf I think it means this:

The most ad-hoc way of thread confiment is by simply saying/documenting in a plain language (like English) to other programmers that they should not access a specific object.

The PDF link mentions:

> You could decide on a set of **conventions** to restrict the use of
>   shared state and then work to have all the code follow
>   them. You **agree** on an order of **who** gets to do what and
>   when that ensures locks aren’t needed. If you manage it,
>   that’s great. However, you are using **100% human-level
>   protection** rather than anything language-level, which can
>   be difficult.
>   Part of an ad-hoc agreement could be that you share state in a
>   very specific way; everything that’s shared is marked as
>   volatile and for each shared object, only one thread is
>   ever allowed to be able to write to it. In a single-writer,
>   multiple-reader scenario, you don’t need synchronization if
>   the variable is volatile.
>   Very fragile and very subtle!

So an example could be as simple as documenting something like this:

```
// Don't use this object in other threads than Thread X
private SomeType someObject;
public SomeType getSomeObject() { return someObject; }
```

or

```
// Don't modify this from any other thread than Thread X.
// So use it read-only for those other threads.
private volatile int someNumber;
```

Although the text in the book:

> describes when the responsibility for maintaining thread confinement falls entirely on the implementation

does make the word "implementation" in this context somewhat unclear. The word suggest code, but the use of the word "documentation" or client implementation/usage of shared data, would be clearer imho.

Answer (score 4):

This means that as a developer it's your responsibility to ensure that no references to the object escape outside the Thread (hence ad-hoc).

For example, if you consider this example (simplified version of stack confinement example in Java Concurrency in Practice)

```
public int countLions(Collection<Animal> animals) {
  int count = 0;
  for (Animal animal : animals) {
      if (animal.getType() == "Lion") {
          count++;
      }
  }
  return count;
}
```

For the local variable count, it would be impossible to obtain a reference to it, hence the language semantics ensure that you can't expose a reference outside. Thus, you have got Stack Confinement. If you were using an Object reference instead of `int count`, then you would have to be a bit more careful not to expose that reference outside the method.

So the ad-hoc thread confinement basically means that the developer has to ensure that the object references are not accidentally exposed to the outside world. In ad-hoc thread confimenet there is no specific language functionality (like Stack Confinement, Thread Local) to aid the developer and it is solely upto the developer to manage Thread Confinement.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this approach means that the thread confinement completely dependent on the programmer to control itself, not provided by the java language syntax guarantee.You look at the ad-hoc meaning of the word will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

In the Book as you read you need if possible, use one of the stronger forms of thread confinment (StackConfirmed or ThreadLocal) instead.

Example classes for them is here:

- [StackConfirmed(Thread confinement of local primitive and reference variables)](http://jcip.net/listings/Animals.java)
- [ThreadLocal(Using ThreadLocal to ensure thread confinement)](http://jcip.net/listings/ConnectionDispenser.java)